# String.subString memory problem

Tags: apex

In Java the String API `subString()` can cause memory problems. The reason is because subString copies the entire string and then just has a different begin and end position.

It looks like APEX has the same behaviour.  Have you noticed this and what is your work around?

Comment: `It looks like APEX has the same behaviour` - do you have some examples?

Comment: This issue was fixed in Java 7, which is probably why it is not an issue in Apex now either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Experiment shows that this is not the case:

```
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
String one = '1234567890'.repeat(10);
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
String two = one.substring(53,63);
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
one = null;
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
```

After the first 100 character String is initialised, 100 extra bytes of Heap are used.
When we take a 10 character substring from this, we see only 10 extra bytes of Heap are used.
When the initial 100 character String is deferenced, the Heap usage drops by 100 bytes.

Comment: thanks. Yes I am finding something similar.  Interesting.

Comment: My memory problems are happening because Apex passes String's by Value rather than by reference.  If you invoke a method with a big string, it is copied and this can put pressure on your heap.

Comment: @MoreThanFive Just like Java, Apex passes everything by value.